# How to load large nt/rdf dump into a Jena/PostgreSQL model (TDB/RDB?)

Tags: postgresql, import, rdf, large-files, jena

I'm using DBpedia in my project.
So far I've been using a SPARQL client, but the performance is far from being acceptable (not to mention the frequent downtime of the end point).

So I want to load the big NT files available at http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads36 in a local dbms (I have a server with PostgreSQL).

In my application (built on Java and Groovy) I open a connection with a Jena persistent graph with:

```
def jenaConnection = new DBConnection( ... )
def maker = ModelFactory.createModelRDBMaker( jenaConnection )
def globalModel = maker.openModel( "my_big_fat_model" )
```

This is OK for a few thousand triples, but when I try to load a large NT file using a reader

```
RDFReader r = m.getReader( "N-TRIPLE")
r.read( inputStreamFromBigFile ... )
```

The performance is appaling. It loads about 2-3K triples per minute, meaning that the whole DBpedia dataset (millions of triples) might take days to load. Other people using JENA with large datasets don't seem to have this issue.

I read that I should use TDB for large datasets (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/) but I don't understand what I am supposed to do with it.

Is it a similar concept to the RDB interface or what? Do I need to load the NT in the PostgreSQL DB?

The JENA documentation doesn't seem to be very clear on this point.

Comment: Have you isolated where the problem is? If you think it is on the PostgreSQL side of things, please include an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the problematic queries? Check out the log_min_duration_statement configuration tunable. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with using PostgresQL as the back-end, you should use [SDB](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/index.html). It's a more up-to-date wrapper for relational stores for Jena models than the old db driver. There is also [quickstart documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/quickstart.html) for getting going with SDB.

TDB is a persistent store that provides an alternative to using a relational database as the back-end triplestore. TDB builds its own b-tree indexes on disk, and manages the caching for you. In every other respect, it appears to the programmer just like a normal Jena `Model`. TDB has command line tools that help with the loading process, although as they are bash scripts they require Linux or cygwin. To load dbpedia, this is what I have done in the past:

```
$> tdbloader2 --loc ./tdb ./source/*.nt
```

where `./source` is the directory where I downloaded the various `.nt` files from dpbedia. It takes a few hours on a reasonable machine, but certainly not days.

Once you have the TDB image in `./tdb`, just follow the [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/java_api.html) to load the `Model` in your Java program:

```
String directory = "./tdb" ;
Model model = TDBFactory.createModel(directory) ;
...
model.close() ;
```

From there, just use `model` as you normally would use any Jena model. There is one caveat: TDB doesn't provide any concurrency support. If your app requires concurrent access to the store (specifically, any writes concurrent with one or more reads) you will need to handle locking at the app level.

Comment: Thanks! I posted an issue I'm having with tdbloader here: http://superuser.com/questions/286388/jena-tdb-tdbloader-on-cygwin-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Looks like a path initialisation issue. Been a while since I used cygwin, but as I recall you had to be careful with the `:` and `;` path separators. Because the `$CLASSPATH` is handed off to the Windows JVM, you have to ensure Windows-style semicolon separators. You may have to tweak the script to do that.  Sorry not to respond on the other forum .. I just can't cope with another channel to keep up with! Feel free to email these questions to the jena-users list at Apache.

Comment: that should be handled automatically by 'make_classpath' which is called by tdbloader.

Comment: TDB runs in-process, so while tdbloader is the recommended way, I've also found writing my own little importer routine works very quick too - less than a second to get 100k triples into TDB.  The other key thing to note is that TDB on 32-bit architectures will grow up to ~1GB of RAM.  On 64 bit architectures, it uses memory mapped files, which just eat available free RAM as defined by the Kernel.  If you are not familiar with this, you may think you are leaking, when you are really just caching.